# Як правильно перекласти "contributed modules"

Tags: переклад, from-english

Дослівний переклад — внесені модулі.

Семантичне значення слова contributed в собі вміщує поняття "наданий для загального користування".

Comment: Я, власне, розімію, про що мова (я програміст). Але було б дуже добре, якби Ви змогли додатково пояснили так, щоб брати участь в дискусії змогли навіть люди з іншим «бекграундом».

Comment: Фактично, «модулі, надані користувачами (чи третіми особами) [для загального користування]» — але як це сказати найкоротше…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У KDE наразі перекладають так:

> [<…> contributed files <…>](//websvn.kde.org/*checkout*/branches/stable/l10n-kf5/uk/messages/kdeedu/org.kde.kwordquiz.appdata.po)
>   <…> файли даних, створені іншими користувачами <…>

У [Drupal](//localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?status=2&release=all&search=contributed&context=all&limit=50) (так, я бачу, що автор сам має відношення до спільноти Drupal і, скоріше за все, особисто це знає чи навіть мав відношення до створення, але наводжу, тому що це може допомогти іншим читачам) використовують різні варіанти:

- *contributed module* (*theme*, *toolkit*, *translation*):

  - *внесений модуль* (*-а тема*, *засіб обробки*, *переклад*)
  - іноді:

    - *наданий модуль* (*-а тема*)
    - *сторонній модуль*
    - *вільно розповсюджуваний модуль* (*-а тема*)
    - *додатковий модуль* (*-а тема*)
- *user-contributed content*:

  - *внесений користувачем вміст*
  - *матеріали, які додали користувачі*
- *user-contributed comments*:

  - *примітки (коментарі) користувачів*